PostgreSQL creating DDL and DML user
I am trying to create a DML user and a DDL user. The DML user should only be able to perform INSERT, DELETE, SELECT, and UPDATE operations on tables, while the DDL user should only be able to create/delete/alter tables but not perform insert, select, etc. I tried creating them with the following code:
CREATE USER ddl WITH PASSWORD '1234'; 
CREATE USER dml WITH PASSWORD '1234'; 

CREATE SCHEMA new_schema; 

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES 
FOR ROLE ddl GRANT INSERT, DELETE, SELECT, UPDATE ON TABLES 
TO dml; 

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES 
FOR ROLE ddl 
IN SCHEMA new_schema 
REVOKE ALL ON TABLES 
FROM ddl;


For the DML user, everything worked perfectly, but for the DDL user, it still has access to all privileges as the owner, and its select, insert, etc., privileges were not revoked. Is it possible to make this kind of change to default privileges?
I expect the DDL user cannot SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, etc, the table he created

The owner has always all privileges: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html

but cant i change this? "this behavior can be changed by altering the global default privileges with ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES." https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html

it doesn't even make sense for a user to have permission to create a table and not "crud" into it.

When you're the owner of the table, the owner of the data. But you're not allowed to do anything with that data, who's going to give anybody the permissions to do something with that data? That will be nobody.

when the table are create the dml user receive the permitions to do something with the data, I understand the questions, I just want to now if is possible and if is how

No, the owner of a table has always access to the data. He could revoke himself, but also grant himself again. The owner has always full control over the content and the structure.
